# Google Analytics & Event Trackers - how to get traffic source by event?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, tracking

I'm using a google events tracker like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1422398-23']);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BookingRequest', 'Parent Name', $('#parent_fname').val()+' '.$('#parent_lname').val()]);
```

In this case, let's say I can track how many requests were submitted.. is there a way to track these specific users, and see the traffic source, and if it's Google, then what keywords they searched my website by?

Basically I want to see the people booking online, and see how and where they got me... and hoping there's a better and more elegant way than to have a field that asks "What did you type into Google to find us?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `fname` and `lname` into GA is a violation of [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html). See number 7 PRIVACY.

Custom vars can be used to determine user type and/or login status. See [Session-level Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples)

> For example, if your website offers users the ability to login, you can use a custom variable scoped to the session level for user login status. In that way, you can segment visits by those from logged in members versus anonymous visitors.

But, don't try to put the username in GA either:

> While the username or user ID is not directly PII, if it is used to tie to a person from a backend system…that’s a violation of the Terms of Service.

To see the traffic source of the events, go to `Content`, `Events`, select the event you want, and add the secondary dimension of `Traffic Source` (just above event title in report).

Here is a [Custom Report for Event Labels](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/permalink?type=custom_report&uid=sB2et-mMQ1KOkzDmJUDNyw) that drills down by source then keyword. Just log into GA and go to the URL.

Comment: Sweet - just read your full answer. Thanks for this - I'll try that out.

Comment: Awesome - this is great for analyzing which search queries return the most action triggers or PDF downloads.